# Summations by conditions on another row dealing with time

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am looking to run a cumulative sum at every row for values that occur in two columns before and after that point. So in this case I have volume of 2 incident types at every given minute over two days. I want to create a column which adds all the incidents that occured before and after for each row by the type. Sumif from excel comes to mind but I'm not sure how to port that over to R:

**EDIT: ADDED set.seed and easier numbers**

I have the following data set:

```
set.seed(42)
master_min = 
  setDT(
    data.frame(master_min = seq(
      from=as.POSIXct("2016-1-1 0:00", tz="America/New_York"),
      to=as.POSIXct("2016-1-2 23:00", tz="America/New_York"),
      by="min"
    ))
  )
incident1= round(runif(2821, min=0, max=10))
incident2= round(runif(2821, min=0, max=10))

master_min = head(cbind(master_min, incident1, incident2), 5)
```

How do I essentially compute the following logic:

**for each row, sum all the incident1s that occured before that row's timestamp and all the incident2s that occured after that row's timestamp?** It would be great to get a data table solution, if not a dplyr as I am working with a large dataset. Below is a before and after for the data`:

BEFORE:

```
              master_min incident1 incident2
   1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00         9         6
   2: 2016-01-01 00:01:00         9         5
   3: 2016-01-01 00:02:00         3         5
   4: 2016-01-01 00:03:00         8         6
   5: 2016-01-01 00:04:00         6         9
```

AFTER THE CALCULATION:

```
              master_min incident1 incident2    new_column
   1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00         9         6    25
   2: 2016-01-01 00:01:00         9         5    29 
   3: 2016-01-01 00:02:00         3         5    33
   4: 2016-01-01 00:03:00         8         6    30
   5: 2016-01-01 00:04:00         6         9    29
```

Comment: Please add `set.seed`. Also, no need in so many observations in order to create a minimal example. Finally, please provide your desired output- unless you want people either ignoring this question or stab in the dark with vogue answers.

Comment: added set.seed and showed a before and after. easier numbers for quick reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
# Cumsum of incident1, without current row:
master_min$sum1 <- cumsum(master_min$incident1) - master_min$incident1

# Reverse cumsum of incident2, without current row:
master_min$sum2 <- rev(cumsum(rev(master_min$incident2))) - master_min$incident2

# Your new column:
master_min$new_column <- master_min$sum1 + master_min$sum2
```

Comment: No, this gives me a vector of (28,32,36,33,32,35), different from the column I'm looking for. Essentially for each row I need the sum of all incident1s before that row + the sum of all incident2s after that row.

Comment: @LoF10 this solution is correct, it's just your data has only 5 rows while his has 6.

Comment: Yes I just realized that, editing my question. Pardon the confusion

Answer (score 0):

*update

The following two lines can do the job

```
master_min$sum1 <- cumsum(master_min$incident1)

master_min$sum2 <- sum(master_min$incident2) - cumsum(master_min$incident2)
```

I rewrote the question a bit to show a bit more comprehensive structure

```
library(data.table)

master_min <-
  setDT(
    data.frame(master_min = seq(
      from=as.POSIXct("2016-1-1 0:00", tz="America/New_York"),
      to=as.POSIXct("2016-1-1 0:09", tz="America/New_York"),
      by="min"
    ))
  )
set.seed(2)

incident1= as.integer(runif(10, min=0, max=10))
incident2= as.integer(runif(10, min=0, max=10))

master_min = cbind(master_min, incident1, incident2)
```

Now master_min looks like this

```
> master_min
             master_min incident1 incident2
 1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00         1         5
 2: 2016-01-01 00:01:00         7         2
 3: 2016-01-01 00:02:00         5         7
 4: 2016-01-01 00:03:00         1         1
 5: 2016-01-01 00:04:00         9         4
 6: 2016-01-01 00:05:00         9         8
 7: 2016-01-01 00:06:00         1         9
 8: 2016-01-01 00:07:00         8         2
 9: 2016-01-01 00:08:00         4         4
10: 2016-01-01 00:09:00         5         0
```

Apply transformations

```
master_min$sum1 <- cumsum(master_min$incident1)

master_min$sum2 <- sum(master_min$incident2) - cumsum(master_min$incident2)
```

Results

```
> master_min
             master_min incident1 incident2 sum1 sum2
 1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00         1         5    1   37
 2: 2016-01-01 00:01:00         7         2    8   35
 3: 2016-01-01 00:02:00         5         7   13   28
 4: 2016-01-01 00:03:00         1         1   14   27
 5: 2016-01-01 00:04:00         9         4   23   23
 6: 2016-01-01 00:05:00         9         8   32   15
 7: 2016-01-01 00:06:00         1         9   33    6
 8: 2016-01-01 00:07:00         8         2   41    4
 9: 2016-01-01 00:08:00         4         4   45    0
10: 2016-01-01 00:09:00         5         0   50    0
```

Comment: Was intended to be an answer but I looked at the question again, seems like only half of the answer. For incident2 he wanted like a reverse cumsum and is different from the operations on incident1

Comment: Hey JP, this is close but not what I'm looking for. Essentially for each row I need the sum of all incident1s before that row + the sum of all incident2s after that row. So with your set.seed(2), the first row has no preceeding incident1s so thats (0 + sum(all incidient2s after row1).